# Using interfaces with POCO objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I am trying to incorporate interfaces in my latest application. With simple classes it seems to be pretty straight forward but with classes with relationships things seem to get weird. What is the correct way to use interfaces with classes with relationship?
My interfaces:

```
   public interface IAgent
    {
        string FirstName { get; set; }
        int Id { get; set; }
        string LastName { get; set; }
        IEnumerable<ITeam> Teams { get; set; }
    }

   public interface ITeam
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        int Id { get; set; }
        IEnumerable<IAgent> Agents { get; set; }
    }
```

My classes end up being:

```
   public class Agent : IAgent
      { 
       public Agent()
        {
            Teams = new HashSet<Team>();
        }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<ITeam> Teams { get; set; }
      }
     public class Team : ITeam
      {
       public Team()
       {
        Agents = new HashSet<Agent>();
       }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<IAgent> Agents { get; set; }
      }
```

Structured this way the POCO classes will not create the relationship table using code first migrations.

And my Context Class:

```
  public class SDRContext :DbContext
{
    public SDRContext():base("SDRContext")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Agent> Agents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("SDR");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is weird to you?

Comment: Sorry hit submit before I was done.

Comment: Change public IEnumerable<IAgent> Agents { get; set; } to be virtual so public virtual ICollection<IAgent> Agents { get; set; }

Also, may try having the DbSet ref the concrete types rather than interfaces and can use the interface in code for dependency injection and stuff. Not a requirement though.

Comment: That still doesn't create the relationship for me.

Comment: Why are you trying to use interfaces with Entity Framework models?

Comment: @BenCottrell For the same reason you'd use an interface on any other class.

Comment: So this is a man-to-many relationship and what Entity will end up doing is creating bridge tables. The bridge table will not have its own primary key but rather it is composed of just foregighn keys. look at (http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).
Are you updating the migration or just creating it. must call update-migration to apply it.
The database should create a TeamAgent table

Comment: Can you post your DbContext class?

Comment: Added the DbContext class.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer because it is not at all clear why you have decided you want to use interfaces rather than concrete types or what you hope to achieve by doing so.

Comment: Trying to learn how interfaces should/could be used in this sort of project.

Comment: An interface can not be instantiated.If you look at your db tables you will not see any foreign keys.